# sql query to get value on maximum date comparing current record date

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-foxpro

I am having 2 tables 
Table1 having fields

```
childid, ondate,       points
1        31/01/2017      50
1        28/02/2017      77
1        31/03/2017      25
```

Table2 having fields

```
childid,    programid,     fromdate
1              1           01/01/2017
1              2           01/03/2017
```

Table2 specifies that the child was in programid 1 from 01/01/2017 to 01/03/2017 and after that he was in programid 2.
So my result should be like

```
childid, ondate,       points    Programid
1        31/01/2017      50          1
1        28/02/2017      77          1
1        31/03/2017      25          2
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:  This answer is for MySQL.

This is a little tricky.  I think a correlated subquery is the simplest method:

```
select t1.*, 
       (select t2.programid
        from table2 t2
        where t2.childid = t1.childid and
              t2.fromdate <= t1.ondate
        order by t1.ondate desc
        limit 1
       ) as programid
from table1 t1
order by t1.ondate desc;
```

This guarantees only one program (per child) on any given date in `table1`.

Comment: @Santosh So don't use a 'discontinued data-centric, object-oriented, procedural, programming language'

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I hadn't even noticed the Foxpro tag.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Only the thing I added in the above query is order by t1.ondate desc

Comment: @Strawberry, limit 1 wouldn't work in MSSQL either. So don't use MSSQL as well? LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.childid, t1.ondate, t1.points, t2.programid
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2  on t1.chilid = t2.childid
                        and t2.fromdate <= t1.ondate;
```

Just join the two tables with `t2.fromdate <= t1.ondate`.

Answer (score 0):

If the query needed to be VFP compatible then it could be:

```
Select tb1.*, tb2.programid ;
    FROM table1 tb1 ;
    inner Join (;
    SELECT *, ;
    NVL((Select Min(fromdate) ;
    from table2 t1;
    WHERE t1.childid=t2.childid And ;
          t1.fromdate > t2.fromdate),Date(9999,12,31)) As toDate ;
    FROM table2 t2 ;
    ) tb2 ;
    ON tb1.childid = tb2.childid And ;
       tb1.ondate >= tb2.fromdate And ;
       tb1.ondate < tb2.toDate
```